# Extract Unique Domain Comparing Two Text Files? Python

Tags: python

I wanted to extract unique domain from new.txt file after comparing it with old.txt file.

Old.txt file and new.txt file both contains domain list but I wanted to extract only the unique domain that exist in new.txt file after comparing it with old.txt file. In short, I wanted to extract domain that exists in new.txt file only.

```
import difflib
with open('new.txt', 'r') as newfile:
        with open('old.txt', 'r') as oldfile:
            with open('uniq.txt', 'w+') as Newdata:
                usedfile = [ x.strip('\n') for x in list(oldfile) ] #1
                masterfile = [ x.strip('\n') for x in list(newfile) ] #2
                for line in masterfile: #3
                    if line not in usedfile: #4
                        Newdata.write(line + '\n') #5
```

I have done using above python code but it is taking lot of time to finish the task, Is there a way to do the task in short period of time like using multitasking or multiprocessing? Please help I have huge list of domain to compare and extract.

Comment: Use a set for `usedfile`

Comment: Also I don't know if memory is an issue but you do not need to read in the whole of the new file into memory. You can read a line at a time, and if it does not exist in the old file, then write it to the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use set operations

```
with open('new.txt', 'r') as newfile:
        with open('old.txt', 'r') as oldfile:
            with open('uniq.txt', 'w+') as Newdata:
                usedfile = set([ x.strip('\n') for x in list(oldfile)]) #1
                masterfile = set([ x.strip('\n') for x in list(newfile)]) #2
                for line in masterfile.diference(usedfile):
                        Newdata.write(line + '\n') #5
```

Comment: `Newdata.write('\n'.join(masterfile-usedfile)`

Comment: thanks it solved the problem, its now very very quick

Comment: @JohnLee Are the lines coming out in the same order as originally?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a set for the contents of the oldfile, because the inclusion testing is O(1) time complexity instead of O(n).  Sets are unordered, but for the lines from the old file (as opposed to those from the new file) the ordering makes no difference because you are only using them for inclusion testing.

Also it may help to avoid reading the whole of the new file into memory.  This will not change the time complexity but it will reduce the memory footprint.

```
with open('old.txt', 'r') as oldfile:
    usedfile = set(x.strip('\n') for x in oldfile)

with open('new.txt', 'r') as newfile, open('uniq.txt', 'w+') as Newdata:
    for line in newfile:
        l = line.strip('\n')
        if l not in usedfile:
            Newdata.write(l + '\n')
```

Note that the expression for `usedfile` uses a generator - there is no need to construct a temporary list in order to create the set.

Separate from the optimisation, you might also wish to replace `strip('\n')` with `strip()` in the two places where it occurs, so that any other whitespace at start/end of the lines is also stripped, not only the newlines.